# Remove duplicate rows on a SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/119896/duplicate-result)
>   [Interview - Detect/remove duplicate entries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649498/interview-detect-remove-duplicate-entries)

I have a SQL Query, which returns a table with one column.

The returned data may be duplicate. for example, my query may be something like:

```
SELECT item FROM myTable WHERE something = 3
```

and the returned data may be something like this:

```
item
-----
2
1
4
5
1
9
5
```

**My Question is, How to remove duplicated items from my query?**

I mean, I want to get these results:

```
item
-----
2
1
4
5
9
```

Please note that I **don't** want to change or delete any rows **in table.** I just want to remove duplicates **in that query**.

How to do that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
SELECT DISTINCT item FROM myTable WHERE something = 3
```

Answer (score 6):

As noted, the `distinct` keyword eliminates duplicate rows—where the rows have identical values in column—from the result set.

However, for a non-trivial query against a properly designed database, the presence of duplicate rows in the result set — and their elimination via `select distinct` or `select ... group by` is, IMHO, most often a "code smell" indicating improper or incorrect join criteria, or a lack of understanding of the cardinalities present in relationships between tables.

If I'm reviewing the code, `select distinct` or gratuitous `group by` without any obvious need present will get the containing query flagged and that query gone over with a fine toothed comb.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the **DISTINCT** keyword to your query.
This keyword is pretty standard and supported on all major databases.

[See DISTINCT refs here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp)

Comment: The tags say `sql-server-2005`...

Comment: the database is in the tag (sql server 2005)

Comment: I'm using SQL Server 2005, and I told that in tags :)

Answer (score 1):

`SELECT DISTINCT item FROM myTable WHERE something = 3`

You just have to use distinct